# Protecting a worksheet seems to protect the whole workbook

Tags: vba, excel

**EDIT**

This was caused by the workbook having become corrupt.

It didn't seem worth answering my own question, but it's pretty difficult to search for in google so I'm leaving this up here in case anyone else has the same issue and chances upon this.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I've got a Sub that protects a sheet and hides columns, or does the reverse depending whether LockSheet is True/False. The idea being that certain users can unlock certain parts of the workbook by entering a password in a dialog box, and the locking also happens automatically before close.
It works fine, except I'm only wanting to protect certain sheets, and my code seems to be doing just that. Except when I open the workbook I get told the whole workbook is protected.

Anyone have any idea why this might be happening? I've never protected the workbook to my knowledge, and tried unprotecting it by code, but still get a password prompt on opening it...

For comprehension: In the code below each "Item" In "SheetCombinationsToProtect" is a structure which has the sheet name and list of columns.

```
Private Sub PerformOperationOnSheetsAndColumns(SheetCombinationsToProtect As Collection, LockSheet As Boolean)

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsName As String
    Dim wsColumns() As String
    Dim Combination As String
    Dim Password As String
    Password = GetPassword()
    For Each Item In SheetCombinationsToProtect
        Combination = Item
        wsName = GetSheetNameFromCombination(Combination)
        wsColumns = GetColumnsFromCombination(Combination)
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(wsName)
        ws.Activate
        ws.Unprotect (Password)
        For Each Col In wsColumns
                ws.Columns(ws.Range(Col & 1).Column).EntireColumn.Hidden = LockSheet
            Next Col
        If LockSheet = True Then
            ws.Protect (Password)
        Else
            ws.Activate
            ws.Cells(1, 1).Show
        End If
    Next Item
    If LockSheet = True Then
        wb.Sheets("Order  Entry").Activate
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: With any cell(s) selected, tap Ctrl+1 and go to the *Protection* tab. You will see that cells are locked by default. As soon as protection of the workbook is enabled, they all become functionally locked. You need to unlock the cells you want universal access to despite workbook protection. See [Password protect worksheet or workbook elements](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Password-protect-worksheet-or-workbook-elements-dbf706e0-ba22-4a08-84d8-552db16eef11).

Comment: If you have resolved the issue it is worth posting your solution as an answer for others to find in the future. You can accept your own post as the answer after a 48 hour period. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: This question is not in any way beneficial for the future visitor. The problem and the solution are no way related to each other. The workbook corruption can result in any kind of discrepancy. I would recommend deleting the question. :)

Comment: @Siddharth Rout: It is beneficial. Worksheet corruption was the cause of this problem, and most likely will be the cause for anyone else encountering this same problem. How many other kinds of discrepancies can be caused by corruption has no bearing whatsoever.

Comment: Then in that case, please leave a proper answer and accept it like @Jeeped mentioned :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the workbook itself was corrupted. This apparently happens on rare occasions, even without macros.

I ported the macros to a previous version of the workbook and all worked fine.